# Matching URL patterns with this template

Tags: regex, url

I'm trying to put together a RegEx that would match certain domain patterns.

It should match this pattern:

```regex
https?://www.domain.com/\*myKeyword\*/,
```

but should NOT match:

```regex
https?://www.domain.com/**something/**\*myKeyword\*/
```

There should be only one forward slash between top-level domain and my keyword and one slash at the end.

This is valid:

```regex
https://www.example.com/the-bla-KEYWORD-bla-bla/
```

But not any of these:

```regex
https://www.example.com/join/the-bla-KEYWORD-bla-bla/
https://www.example.com/gift/the-bla-KEYWORD-bla-bla/?coupon=yes
https://www.example.com/user/forgot-password/?next=/the-bla-KEYWORD-bla-bla/
```

I tried:

```regex
^https?:\/\/.*?\.?example\.com\/.[^\/].*KEYWORD.*\/
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just repeat the negated class, not the dot:

```regex
^https?://.*?\.?example\.com/[^/]*KEYWORD[^/]*/$
```

[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/cptOH1/5/)

`[^/]*` matches any character but `/`. We allow anything but `/` after `/`, then a `KEYWORD` and then again anything but `/` until the final `/`. We also add `$` to match until the end of the string (otherwise URLs with `/` after keyword will be partially matched).